# fileno and reference weakening confusion

Tags: perl

Im trying to use fileno to make a table of file handles for my threads and I have encountered a situation which I can't quite understand. consider the following code:

```
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
my %fhh; #this is shared, but that's not important for my issue
open my $fh , '>', 'out1.txt' ;
$fhh{1} = fileno $fh;
open my $fh , '>', 'out2.txt' ;
$fhh{2} = fileno $fh;
open my $fh , '>', 'out3.txt' ;
$fhh{3} = fileno $fh;
open my $fh , '>', 'out4.txt' ;
$fhh{4} = fileno $fh;
print Dumper \%fhh;
```

the output i get is:

```
$VAR1 = {
          '4' => '9',
          '1' => '6',
          '3' => '8',
          '2' => '7'
        };
```

So far so good, unfortunately I need to generate an unknown number of handles, so i tried the following code:

```
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
my %fhh;
foreach my $i (1 .. 4){
    my $file = "out" . $i . ".txt";
    open my $fh , '>',  $file ;
    $fhh{$i} = fileno $fh;
}
print Dumper \%fhh;
```

here i get the output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          '4' => '10',
          '1' => '10',
          '3' => '10',
          '2' => '10'
        };
```

so something is wrong, perhaps here $fh gets weakened and lost? so i tried the following:

```
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
my %fhh;
my @mfw;
foreach my $i (1 .. 4){
    my $file = "out" . $i . ".txt";
    open my $fh , '>',  $file ;
    push @mfw, $fh; 
    $fhh{$i} = fileno $fh;

}
print Dumper \%fhh;
```

here the output is correct again, like in the first example, so it seems it is indeed a weakening issue, but then why isn't this happening in the first example? I am redefining $fh every time and even if i surround the whole block in {} it still works fine, could some one explain to me whats going on?
I'm on perl 5.14 if thats important

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `my $fh` is scoped to the enclosing block. This variable is the only reference to the file handle. When the file handle is destroyed the file is closed, and the file descriptor number can be reused for the next file. The FD is just an integer, it has no magic to keep the file open.

By keeping references to the opened file handles in an array, you've extended the lifetime of the file handles. Therefore each new file gets a new FD number.

Comment: hmm i see. i tried  splitting my first example into 4 blocks and the issue indeed occurs. so when im redefining a variable in the same block the previous content doesn't get weakened?

Comment: @Nullman There are no weak references in your code. Perl uses reference counting to manage garbage collection. If the reference count of an object drops to zero, the object is destroyed. Variables with `my` only exist until the end of the block. A file descriptor is not a reference that Perl recognizes. In your last example the array keeps referencing the file handles so they are not destroyed.

Comment: so when i redefine $fh in the first example, the previously opened file handle is still open somewhere in memory until the block ends, but in a loop it closes at the end of each iteration? does that mean that each iteration of a loop is a separate block?

Comment: i found a [perl monks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1009647) explenation, it seems that loops iterations are indeed indipendant

Comment: Yes, each time the `my` is executed you get a *new* variable. The old variable with the same name still exists, but is not visible. In contrast, the variables inside your loop body are destroyed at the end of the block.